# Android Is it possible to use menu with themes

Tags: android, menu, themes

In my app the user can choose from 4 different themes. The time has come to create different menu icons for the different themes, but the icons do not show in the menu items. Any ideas?

**Menu:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/Menu1"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        style="?menu_addtolist" />
```

**attrs.xml**

```
<attr name="menu_addtolist" format="reference" />
```

**themes.xml**

```
<item name="menu_addtolist">@style/menu_green_addtolist</item>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="menu_green_addtolist">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/menu_addtolist_green</item>
</style>
```

I did everything the way I had done with the other objects (buttons, layouts, texts). When I select a theme, the full theme changes, but there are no menu icons.

I changed the style in the menu item to another one I use in the app as a button style, and that did not make a change, while that style is definitely working. Maybe it is not possible to apply styles to menu items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer is no. It is not possible to use themes with menu. Maybe because the menu has no (available) layout